# Copying Existing Code To A New Website

Tags: joomla

I have got two website and i want to use an element from 1 that is a comparison module that has been created. I want to place it within my Joomla website and change the look and feel of it.

What is the best way to get this element into a Joomla website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recreate the component or module from scratch in the new site, and start to copy the coding and styling.

Comment: Does this have to be done within Joomla, or can i just do it with my hosting area?

Comment: Well, you'll need to install it using Joomla, but you can then just FTP the files from one to the other